# hibernate reverse engineering persistence unit not found

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa

I havea java maven3 project in Eclipse IDE with jboss tools installed. I'm using hibenrate4

I'm triing to setup the hibenrate configuratoin in hibernate view to test hql queries, the problem is that is says that it couldnt find the persistence unit. I have the persistence.xml placed in src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml

is there some maven config that I nead to set?

[image: project structure]

[image: hibenrate configuration]

[image: hibernate configuration]

[image: persistence unit not found error]

Persistence.xml

```
   <persistence-unit  name="ypay">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ypay</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
     <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
     <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" /> -->
     <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
     <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect" />  
    </properties>
```

hibernate.properties

```
hibernate.connection.password=
hibernate.connection.username=root
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://****************:3306/ypay?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8
hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider
hibernate.datasource=
hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class=
```

Comment: @Andrei It was wotking in previews projects, in eclipse juno with both files, now in kepler I have problems, I dont see the reason why both files should not be there

Comment: @simonC Is it not the case that if META-INF/persistence.xml is already on your classpath, you don't need to explicitly select a persistence unit?

Comment: @JamesB is I remove the persistence unit entry  from the hibernate edit configurations the problem persists, in this case it says "persistence unit not found : null"

Comment: @Andrei ... i nead hibernate-cfg.properties only for the purpouse of reverse engineering and hql query testing via jboss hibenrate tools in eclise, the aplication itself uses a datasource ... I have used many times both files in an aplication withowt problems

Comment: Do you have a single persistene.xml file in your project? Don't you have another one in test/resources/META_INF? PS: I deleted my comments as I do not consider them useful.

Comment: @Andrei there is not other persistence.xml only in src/main/resources/META-INF

Comment: @Andrei ... it is not the bug in the aplication, I want to make reverse enginering from database with to create entities, and to have the ability to test the hql via the HQL editor ... the aplication itself is working ok

Comment: @simonC Concerning the reveng db to entities, the following tool may help you: https://github.com/sp00m/db2jpa.

Comment: @sp00m tnx for the info but i would like to have this working in eclipse, so I can test hql queries in the IDE

Comment: please check this link related your problem. https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/issues/667

Comment: what does the detail say

Comment: @JigarJoshi the details say nothing useful .... org.hibernate.console.HibernateConsoleRuntimeException: Persistence unit not found: 'ypay'.
Persistence unit not found: 'ypay'.
  <No message>

Answer (score 0):

You need a `META-INF/persistence.xml` with

```
<persistence-unit name="ypay">
```

(usually put it in WEB-INF/classes/META-INF. When using maven you can try placing  it in src/main/resources/META-INF)

Please refer to [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/configuration.html#setup-configuration-packaging) doc for details.

Comment: I have a persistence.xml and inside a persistence unit with the name ypay it is placed in META-INF but in the EJB part of the ear project not in the war, as I said in previous comments the application itself is working ok when I run it, the problem is when I try to configure a connection in hibernate tools in eclipse, which I would like to use for testing the queries. I will try to place the persistence.xml also in war but I'm quite skeptik that it will work.

Comment: I dont even have a src/main/resources/META-INF in the war, but I have it in the ejb project, as you can see on the first picture